# bind_cols() dataframe on the left hand side in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am wondering if there's a way to bind a dataframe on the left hand side instead of putting them on the right hand side through `dplyr()`. This is because when I am working on a long `dplyr()` cleaning on the second dataset and the final step is to bind the dataset to the first dataset (main dataset). If I use `bind_cols()`, the second dataset is always joined on the right hand side. Is there a way I can force the first dataset to join on the left hand side of the second dataset in a long dplyr script.

- Obviously, I can make one line syntax indepdently and start with the first dataset and use `bind_cols()` to bind it with the second dataset. I am just wondering if there's anyting I can do at the end of a long dplyr script?

```
first_dataset <- mtcars[1:3]
second_dataset <- mtcars[4:5]

second_dataset %>% bind_cols(first_dataset)

                     hp drat  mpg cyl  disp
Mazda RX4           110 3.90 21.0   6 160.0
Mazda RX4 Wag       110 3.90 21.0   6 160.0
Datsun 710           93 3.85 22.8   4 108.0
Hornet 4 Drive      110 3.08 21.4   6 258.0
Hornet Sportabout   175 3.15 18.7   8 360.0
Valiant             105 2.76 18.1   6 225.0
Duster 360          245 3.21 14.3   8 360.0
Merc 240D            62 3.69 24.4   4 146.7
Merc 230             95 3.92 22.8   4 140.8
Merc 280            123 3.92 19.2   6 167.6
```

Expected output:

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Introducing magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html):

> When the LHS is needed at a position other than the first, one can use the dot,`.`, as placeholder.

Try:

```
second_dataset %>% bind_cols(first_dataset,.)
```